# Preventing XSS (Cross-site Scripting)

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, security, xss

Let's say I have a simple ASP.NET MVC blog application and I want to allow readers to add comments to a blog post.  If I want to prevent any type of XSS shenanigans, I could HTML encode all comments so that they become harmless when rendered.  However, what if I wanted to *some* basic functionality like hyperlinks, bolding, italics, etc?

I know that StackOverflow uses the [WMD Markdown Editor](http://wmd-editor.com/), which seems like a great choice for what I'm trying to accomplish, if not for the fact that it supports *both* HTML and Markdown which [leaves it open to XSS attacks](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2008/06/safe-html-and-xss/).

Comment: For search reasons, it might be helpful to change the title to "Preventing XSS (Cross-site scripting)" to the title. For someone who doesn't know its friendly name, XSS, they may have a harder time finding this thread.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you are not looking to use an editor you might consider [OWASP's AntiSamy](http://www.owasp.org/index.php/Category:OWASP_AntiSamy_Project_.NET).

You can run an example here: 
http://www.antisamy.net/

Answer (score 3):

How much HTML are you going to support? Just bold/italics/the basic stuff? In that case, you can convert those to markdown syntax and then strip the rest of the HTML.

The stripping needs to be done server side, before you store it. You need to validate the input on the server as well, when checking for SQL-vulnerabilities and other unwanted stuff.

Comment: Right on. Take a whitelist approach--not a black list approach.

Answer (score 2):

If you need to do it in the browser: http://code.google.com/p/google-caja/wiki/JsHtmlSanitizer

Comment: you can never trust user input, everything that comes from the browser might be tampered

Comment: @rjlopes - That isn't a problem if you're trying to sanitize content from a server for presentation in the client.

Comment: my fault I assumed that it was to apply on the client before submitting the information to the server. However in this particular case (you control, the server) it doesn't make much sense to sanitize on the client. The only case it should be useful is when you do ajax requests to third party websites.

Comment: @rjlopes It can happen on the client legitimately as well, just not in a way the server relies on.  An Ajax heavy application often needs to sync state b/w the browser and server.  When the user changes something, the client optimistically updates its model before sending it to the server to update the authoritative model so that the ajax application appears responsive.  A comment edit box is a good example.  Stack overflow's question editor allows the user to write some mix of markdown/HTML, which it can render in a preview pane without a server round-trip as the user types.

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest you only submit the markdown syntax. On the front end, the client can type markdown and have an HTML preview (same as SO), but only submit the markdown syntax server-side. Then you can validate it, generate the HTML, escape it and store it.

I believe that's the way most of us do it. In either case, markdown is there to alleviate anyone from writing structured HTML code and give power to those who wouldn't even know how to.

If there's something specific you'd like to do with the HTML, then you can tweak it with some CSS inheritance '.comment a { color: #F0F; }', front end JS or just traverse over the generated HTML from parsing markdown before you store it.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you use Jeff's code ? http://refactormycode.com/codes/333-sanitize-html

Answer (score 1):

I'd vote for the [FCKEditor](http://www.fckeditor.net/) but you have to do some [extra steps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65734/how-do-use-fckeditor-safely-without-risk-of-cross-site-scripting) to the returned output [too](http://htmlpurifier.org/).

Answer (score 0):

You could use an HTML whitelist so that certain tags can still be used, but everything else is blocked.

There are tools that can do this for you. SO uses [the code](http://refactormycode.com/codes/333-sanitize-html) that [Slough linked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/445177/preventing-xss#445231).